# Generate long numeric id of type String with auto increment

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot, h2

I need to save entity with numeric id(15-25 digits) to `H2` db. Since db doesn't support `BigInteger`(it's mapped to `Decimal`), the only way to save such long numbers is `String` type.

Question: How I can generate such a numeric id of `String` type with auto increment?

**UPDATE**

ID should looks like: 123456789012345 (min 15 digits, max 25 digits)

Comment: Or `UUID.randomUUID().toString()`. But Long is possible: http://www.h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#identity_type

Comment: The UUID format('550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000') isn't appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use a `BigInteger` behind the scenes.

Something like this should work for any number of digits and is thread safe.

```
private static final AtomicReference<BigInteger> id = new AtomicReference<>(BigInteger.ZERO);

public String nextId() {
    BigInteger next = id.accumulateAndGet(BigInteger.ONE, (x, y) -> x.add(y));
    return next.toString();
}

public void test(String[] args) {
    for ( int i = 0; i < 100; i++ ) {
        System.out.println(nextId());
    }
}
```

If your limits (15 - 25 digits) is hard then something like this would probably do.

```
private static final int MIN_DIGITS = 2;
private static final int MAX_DIGITS = 3;
private static final BigInteger start = BigInteger.TEN.pow(MIN_DIGITS-1);
private static final BigInteger limit = BigInteger.TEN.pow(MAX_DIGITS).subtract(BigInteger.ONE);

private static final AtomicReference<BigInteger> id = new AtomicReference<>(start);

public String nextId() {
    BigInteger next = id.accumulateAndGet(BigInteger.ONE, (x, y) -> {
        if(x.compareTo(limit) >= 0) {
            // Back to start.
            return start;
        }
        return x.add(y);
    });
    return next.toString();
}

public void test(String[] args) {
    for ( int i = 0; i < 1000; i++ ) {
        System.out.println(nextId());
    }
}
```

Note that for testing I have set the limits to `2` and `3`. You can adjust to your taste.

Comment: I don't see any reference to existing ids in db. Is there possible duplicated ids? Especially If we will restart an application

Comment: @user1376885 - You will have to prime the initial value at startup from the db.

Answer (score 0):

Use IDENTITY(START WITH 10000000000), java Long, autoincrement: http://www.h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#identity_type

Comment: It will be the most easiest way if I can do so but Long supports max 19 symbols only. I need max 25 symbols. That's why I stucked on the way how to do so.

Comment: @user1376885 why do you need max 25 symbols and why should it be autoincrement? Your requirements are bizarre.

Comment: There is no explanation why 25 symbols is necessary, it's just requirement in the scope of test task. As for autoincrement, it's mine assumption how to make ids unique.

Comment: @user1376885 don't assume things, and clear up your requirements. What you're trying to do now with your "autoincrementing String" is just ridiculous.

Comment: I'll try to clarify requirements. One question to you, if there will be requirement to use Long type for ids but with min digits = 10 and max digits = 15, how I can set these limits?

Comment: Min digits could be controlled by the starting value of the autoincrement generator. How? I do not know at the moment, sorry. Validation on generated keys is a bit weird, simply having `INT(15)` seems okay.